# Add message to Add Article page

Tags: nodes, entities

In the Add Article page (while editing), how do I add a custom message right above or below the Save/Preview buttons?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [markup](http://drupal.org/project/markup) module to add html text as fields to the article content type.

If you want to show the html text only in edit page then you need to use hook form alter

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form' && arg(2) == "edit") {    
    $form['contact_information'] = array(
      '#markup' => 'Your message goes here !',
    );
  }  
}
```

Comment: What is "contact_information"? Is that the name of the form? Should there be a generic ID for the article creation node?

Also, is there a way to add css styles to that as well? It looks like those "widgets" are in iframes so the sites' styles don't apply to them.